# Should flags in POSIX-style operating systems be prefixed by "no" or "no_"?

Tags: coding-style, posix, flags, command-line-arguments

When you have a boolean option and a flag for setting it to false by prefixing "no" to the name, should it be "no" or "no_"? What's most commonly used or better style? For example:

```
--no_foo
```

or

```
--nofoo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither. Use `no-` i.e. `--no-foo`.